# Adding pseudo-element between two elements

Tags: html, css

I would like to insert a pseudo-element between two elements, in e.g.:

```css
.general {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
}

.left-subtitle {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right-subtitle {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.right-subtitle:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  left: -100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <h3 class="title">Foo</h3>
  <div class="subtitle">
    <div class="left-subtitle">Text1</div>
    <div class="right-subtitle">9.00 €</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the blue `::after` to get the full width and being fully between yellow and red elements?
I tried to use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.general {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
}

.subtitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.subtitle:after {
  content: '';
  width: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 2px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.left-subtitle {
  padding-right: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.right-subtitle {
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <h3 class="title">Foo</h3>
  <div class="subtitle">
    <div class="left-subtitle">Text1 is longer, so doesn't work</div>
    <div class="right-subtitle">9.00 €</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can I achieve this without adding any `js` files? (I could add them, but it would be better without adding them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use flexbox like so:

```css
.general {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #4a4a4a;
}

.subtitle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.left-subtitle {
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.right-subtitle {
  padding-left: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.left-subtitle:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
  <h3 class="title">Foo</h3>
  <div class="subtitle">
    <div class="left-subtitle">Text1</div>
    <div class="right-subtitle">9.00 €</div>
  </div>
</div>
```